# Chamar um form e fechar um form no mesmo evento

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Como faço para chamar um *form* e fechar um *form* no mesmo evento.
Por exemplo:

```
private void iniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
    Frm1 newForm2 = new Frm1();
    newForm2.ShowDialog();  
}
```

Comment: só pra dizer q :
eu coloquei o Close(); na ultima linha e n deu em nada... a primeira form continua aberta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso se faz colocando o segundo form em uma Thread:

```
public static void ThreadProc()
{
    Application.Run(new Frm1());
}

private void iniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Antes de iniciar o novo thread, não seria melhor garantir que o appartment state é STA (chamando `t.SetAppartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`? E definir `t.IsBackground = true` para que o processo não termine ao fechar o anterior form principal? Faz muito tempo que não faço coisas destas...

Comment: Fiz o mais simples possível, mas você tem razão. Vou atualizar a resposta. Valeu!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, eu estava com o mesmo problema que o nosso colega @AndersonBP mencionou,
aí pesquisando na internet, encontrei uma resposta do @JuniorTunjr que foi mais fácil de compreender e solucionou o meu problema.

```
    private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form f = new frm2();
        f.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close(); 
        f.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a linha this.Hide(); para fechar sua tela de LOGIN, Como no exemplo abaixo.

```
private void iniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
Frm1 newForm2 = new Frm1();
this.Hide(); // use dessa maneira.
newForm2.ShowDialog();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Deu erro algumas vezes, porém com calma consegui executar:

```html
private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form f = new frm2();
        f.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close(); 
        f.Show();
    }
```

A estrutura para copiar e colar é a seguinte:

this.Hide();
[nome_da_sua_form] frm = new nome_da_sua_form;
frm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
frm.Show();

O que estiver entre [] (colchetes), coloque o nome da form que você quer chamar. Por exemplo:

```
    private void voltarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        frm_Menu frm = new frm_Menu();
        frm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Com isso podemos voltar para uma janela anterior ou avançar para outra, entenderam? Muito obrigado amigo Danillo Victtor!

Answer (score -1):

tenta esta no meu deu certo

visible = false;